# how to colour the outline of my text black in xml for android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, drawable, android-xml

i want to make the white coloured text in my android app have a black outline. I do not want to colour the textview so if that is your help then no i already know how to do this. I want to make this happen by using a drawable file in xml format. so is there away i can outline the edges of my text in xml?

Answer (score 16):

One way is to use `shadow`:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:shadowColor="#000000"
    android:shadowDx="0.0"
    android:shadowDy="0.0"
    android:shadowRadius="2.0" />
```

This gives white text a black outline. Adjust the radius accordingly to how thick you'd like it.

Comment: this does not work at all when i put it in xml the text is just white

Comment: what device are you testing on? Try changing the radius to something bigger. Here's how it looks for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9gdSs.png

Comment: yes it works but the black is blurry is there nothing to make the black a solid colour

Comment: like this link    http://catlikecoding.com/unity/documentation/text-shaders/text-smooth-outline-foo.png

Comment: Have you considered using a custom font? http://www.fontspace.com/category/outline

Comment: do you know how to use a font style downloaded from fontspace. if so can you let me know how to import it and use it in xml

Comment: You have to do it in code. Basically you download it, put it in your /assets/ directory, then in code you `.setTypeface()` on your `TextView`. There are some tutorials online: http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-custom-font-example

Comment: it's very useful. tanx